# combinar vetores por linha em R preenchendo espaços vazios

Tags: r

Tenho dois vetores:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,2)
```

Quero criar uma matriz combinando os vetores por linha que seja assim:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 0 0
```

Ou seja, unir dois vetores por linhas e preencher com zeros os espaços vazios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe a função `smartbind` do pacote `gtools` que faz o que você necessita

```
library(gtools)
smartbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,2), fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode aumentar o vetor `b` para ficar do mesmo tamanho do vetor `a` incluindo zeros:

```
rbind(a, b = c(b, rep(0, length(a) - length(b))))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    1    2    3    4
b    1    2    0    0
```